# Does clicking mouse wheel (which makes pointer into double headed arrow) and moving mouse up or down scroll page faster in windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, logitech-mouse

I used to click the mouse wheel which transformed the pointer into a double headed arrow and I moved the mouse up or down to scroll back and forth. This worked on windows 7 and I don't remember using this feature since moving to windows 10.

Its either that feature was removed or the mouse I upgraded to, Logitech M235 doesn't support this feature.

I am gonna buy a new mouse and I wanna know if some other mouse model support it on windows 10.

Comment: My Logitech M535 Mouse (not new) still does that in Windows 10 and 11.

Answer (score 2):

Using the middle mouse button to scroll is a feature that is only present in applications that support it.

While I can use this in my browser, or in Microsoft Excel and Microsoft Word, I cannot use this in Explorer.

As far as I know, this is not mouse dependend, but only program depended. Eg, a mouse without scroll wheel but with a 3rd mouse button should still be able to perform this feature, as it was meant to be used with mouses that don't have a scroll wheel.

Comment: I tried it on chrome, excel. It's not working on Logitech M235 mouse.

Comment: Have you maybe altered the function of the third mouse button (aka scroll wheel)? Otherwise, see if you can install drivers.

Comment: I got this software called logitech options and I have configured the mouse wheel click to middle button.

Comment: If you configure it to something else that you can test, do that and see if its not actually your middle click that is broken.

Comment: I configured it to back and its not working. I don't think its broken because I never remember the middle wheel click working.

Comment: Well, apparently, given that you configure it to something else, and that is not working either, it appears your middle mouse button is in fact broken. You can try and see if you can make it type a letter and then type something in notepad. The most basic test. If you have other buttons, see if you can make those the middle mouse button and see if that allows you to scroll.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134728/discussion-between-user6658170-and-lpchip).